# Constant Editor Revert button removes whole entry?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

If in the constants field I put this:

```
# cat=basic/enable/1; type=; label= My Variable
myVariable =
```

I get an empty field in the Constant Editor as expected. 
But then next to the field is a revert button that removes the whole variable from the editor.

How do I set this so that it will not be removed with the revert button?

I am working without extentions in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I found that by setting the constants in an external file like this:

```
<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE:fileadmin/templates/mysite/Configuration/Typoscript/constants.typoscript">
```

It will keep them intact.